# Counting the vowels included between two consonants

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to find, from a sentence, the words that contains two vowels between two `r` using java. So I read in the sentence and then I have to find the words that match the criteria described above. For instance if I have a string such as: "roar soccer roster reader" the method `matches` should return `true` for the words "roar" and "roster"

This is the method I come up with, which is doing the job

```
public boolean matches(String singleWord)
{
    // set count to -1. it will increase to 2 if a 'r' is found, it decreases for each vowel    
    int count = -1;
    // loop through a single word
    for (int i=0; i<singleWord.length(); i++){
        // if a 'r' is found set the count to two
        if(singleWord.charAt(i) == 'r'){
            // when count it's 0 exit loop
            if (count == 0)
                return true;
            count = 2;}
        // if I find a vowel count decreases
        else if(isVowel(singleWord.charAt(i))){
            count--;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it seems a bit clumsy... any suggestion on how to improve it or make it simpler? thanx!!!

just in case, this is the `isVowel` method

```
  private boolean isVowel(char c)
{
    String s = c + "";
    return "aeiou".contains(s);
}
```

Comment: What about `reader`? Also, are there any restrictions, like not using regular expressions?

Comment: Should the method return `true` for the string `"rarar"`?

Comment: @tobias_k no there are no restrictions a part the fact that I don't know regular expressions much...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it should return false

Comment: @mikey Interesting... So an `r` in the middle breaks the sequence then, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a straightforward algorithm without loops:

- Find the index of the first `'r'`
- Find the index of the last `'r'`
- Cut the substring in between the two
- Return `true` if removing all vowels from the substring shortens it at least by two characters.

Here is how you can implement it:

```
boolean matches(String singleWord) {
    int from  = singleWord.indexOf('r');
    int to = singleWord.lastIndexOf('r');
    if (from < 0 || from == to) return false;
    String sub = singleWord.substring(from+1, to);
    return (sub.length() - sub.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "").length()) == 2;
}
```

Here is how it works step by step, using the word `"roadster"` as an example:

- `from = 0`, `to = 7`
- `sub = "oadste"`; length is 6
- `sub` after replacement is `"dst"`; length is 3
- The expression `(6 - 3) == 2` is 3, not 2, so `false` is returned.

**EDIT :** The sequence must contain exactly two vowels, with no intervening `'r'`s.

This makes a problem slightly different, because the trick with the first and the last index no longer applies. However, a regex to match the desired sequence can be constructed relatively easily - here it is:

```
"r[^raeiou]*[aeiou][^raeiou]*[aeiou][^raeiou]*r"
```

In order to understand this regexp, all you need to know is that `[...]` matches any character inside brackets, `[^...]` matches any character except the ones in brackets, and `*` matches the preceding subexpression zero or more times.

The expression is lengthy, but it is composed of trivial pieces. It matches as follws:

- An initial `r`
- Zero or more non-vowels except `r`
- The first vowel
- Zero or more non-vowels except `r`
- The second vowel
- Zero or more non-vowels except `r`
- The closing `r`

Here is a simple implementation:

```
boolean matches(String singleWord) {
    return singleWord
        .replaceAll("r[^raeiou]*[aeiou][^raeiou]*[aeiou][^raeiou]*r", "")
        .length() != singleWord.length();
}
```

Comment: wow thanx! Only thing is that `"roadster"` should return false since there are three vowels between the two `r`s

Comment: i guess it just a matter of changing `(sub.length() - sub.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "").length()) >= 2;` to `(sub.length() - sub.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "").length()) == 2;`

Comment: @mikey I think you accepted too early: this one would return `true` for `"rarar"`.

Comment: @mikey This isn't a trivial fix, because the trick with the first and last index no longer works. There is a regex for this, but it's somewhat complex. I'll post an edit soon.

Comment: you know I think that you spot a fault in the specs...  the exercises asks me to count the words in a sentence that contains two vowels between two `r`s.. to test the program I am given a bunch of words but there are none such as rarar.. so I am not sure anymore if `rarar` should return `true` or `false`.. sorry about that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why do you use `replaceAll()` and check `length()` instead of just using `matches()` (see my answer) ?

Comment: @FlorentBayle OP made this comment to an answer that is now deleted: "I just wonder if the method `matches` can be changed in a simpler one". That's why I picked `replaceAll` as a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
public static boolean matches(final String singleWord) {
    return singleWord.matches(".*r([^aeiour]*[aeiou]){2}[^aeiour]*r.*");
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
for (String word: "roar soccer roster reader rarar".split(" "))
    System.out.println(word+":"+matches(word));
```

And here is the output:

```
roar:true
soccer:false
roster:true
reader:false
rarar:false
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a regular expression:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("\w*r\w*([aeiou]\w*){2}r\w*", "roar soccer roster reader");
```

Comment: This does not work if there is a non-vovel between the rs. I'd use something like `\w*r\w*([aeiou]\w*){2}r\w*`

Comment: Yeah you are right, but my knowledge of regular expression is a disaster. I should learn that topic

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, that's definitely better. Edited the post.